# multiple attribute query from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, pivot

i have a question here... i have a 3 tables like this...

customer

```
idCustomer | namaCustomer | email   | noTelp 
__________________________________________________
1          |  Wawan       | a@a.com | 08985623895
```

attribute

```
idAttribute | Name   | publish
______________________________
1           | Gender |  Y
2           | Hobby  |  Y
3           | Job    |  Y
4           | Mission|  N
```

Customer attribute

```
idCustomer  |  idAttribute   | value 
_____________________________________
1           |   1            | Male
1           |   2            | Hacking
1           |   3            | IT Support
```

The question is.. what query statement if i want to get the query from that 3 tables and get the result like this

```
idCustomer | namaCustomer | email   | noTelp      | Gender  | Hobby   | Job
___________________________________________________________________________________
1          |  Wawan       | a@a.com | 08985623895 | Male    | Hacking | IT Support
```

So the table column was added from customer attribute data, but before that we must look attribute tabel that the attribute is published or not (looking for publish value)

anyone can help me here???

great thanks before

Comment: There's a reason EAV (entity-attribute-value; basically, all data in one column) schemas suck.  Actually, a bunch of reasons.  This is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  c.idCustomer,
  c.namaCustomer,
  c.email,
  c.noTelp, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'Gender' THEN ca.value END) AS 'Gender',
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'Hobby'  THEN ca.value END) AS 'Hobby',
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'Job'    THEN ca.value END) AS 'Job'
FROM Customerattribute ca
INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer
GROUP BY ca.idCustomer
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a408/7)

However, for future use of this query for new attributes, you have to do it dynamically like so:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(a.Name = ''',
      a.Name, ''', ca.value, NULL)) AS ',
      a.Name )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Customerattribute ca
INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute
INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer
WHERE a.publish = 'Y';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  c.idCustomer,  c.namaCustomer, '
  ' c.email, c.noTelp, ', @sql, ' FROM Customerattribute ca',
 ' INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute', 
' INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer',
' GROUP BY c.idCustomer');

SELECT @sql;

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [Dynamic Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a408/29)

Comment: I'm fairly certain you're going to have to join the attributes table (or your subquery) three times and query each attribute separately.  Otherwise, you're going to get up to three rows for each customer, each with all but one attribute column nulled out.

Comment: yeah its works. but there's a problem, how if i add new data on attribute (5 | IP) and then add it to Customer attribute ( 1|5|192.0.0.1).. am i must declare MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name ..... again??

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - For this you have to use dynamic sql. See my edit.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal great it works, 1 last question... how can i use that query on php?? am i just wrap all that code using " or ' or how??
thanknyou

Comment: @Mahmoud: Eh.  I hate dynamically generated SQL, but it works.  And that's about the only way you're going to get attributes that aren't hard-coded.  +1, i guess.  :)

Comment: @cHao - I hated too, I always try to stick with the standard normal SQL statements. But what to use for these cases?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: Personally, i prefer schemas that don't suck.  :)  It's not that hard to add a column if you need it, and having a column per attribute adds the ability to enforce constraints and data types and such.

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - To use this with php, put it in a stored procedure. And call this procedure from PHP.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal i try to use your query statement on mysql workbench and i get error code : 1064 and error is at PREPARE stmt FROM @ sql action.. can you help me??

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - It is propably a syntax erro. check your syntax again, and watch out the spaces and the semicolon `;` at the end of each line. Also show me the full error you got.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Kelamin,MAX(IF(a.Name = 'Job', ca.value, NULL)) AS Job FROM cust_attribute ca IN' at line 1

thats my error... how?

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - What is `Kelamin`?? can you please post the output of the `SELECT @sql` from your query you are using?

Comment: Kelamin is the data in my attribute (kelamin = gender)... here's the output...

Comment: 'SELECT  c.idCustomer,  c.namaCustomer,  c.email, c.noTelp, MAX(IF(a.Name = \'Jenis Kelamin\', ca.value, NULL)) AS Jenis Kelamin,MAX(IF(a.Name = \'Job\', ca.value, NULL)) AS Job FROM cust_attribute ca INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute INNER JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer GROUP BY c.idCustomer'

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - Why there is `\'`  in `\'Jenis Kelamin\'` and `a.Name = \'Job\'` ?? Try to write it like `'Jenis Kelamin'` and `'Job'`

Comment: 'SELECT  c.idCustomer,  c.namaCustomer,  c.email, c.noTelp, MAX(IF(a.Name = ''Jenis Kelamin'', ca.value, NULL)) AS Jenis Kelamin,MAX(IF(a.Name = ''Job'', ca.value, NULL)) AS Job FROM cust_attribute ca INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute INNER JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer GROUP BY c.idCustomer' here....

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - use single quots `''` instead of double quots `" "`

Comment: But how??? that double quotes are generated from your query.. i'm not edit anything on your query

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - It shouldn't generate it this way as you can see in the fiddle demo. Try it in the phpmyadmin, and from your code directly

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - What was the problem?

Comment: The value, "Jenis Kelamin" <-- it using space that break the query.. :) but.. now.. i was confused.. how to create the stored procedure.. i always getting error.. :'(

Comment: @WawanBrutalx - You can start a new question with the new issue. But mention it clearly and post the full code you are using, the error you got. So that other users can help you as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19060/discussion-between-wawan-brutalx-and-mahmoud-gamal)